# How to return a new array of object from object nested props with reduce in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I'm trying to return a new `array` of `objects` from the nested properties of another `object`. This is my current `object`:

```
const teams = {
  GRYFFINDOR: {
    display: 'Gryffindor',
    channel: ['#team-gryffindor'],
    ui: 'lion',
  },
  HUFFLEPLUFF: {
    display: 'Hufflepuff',
    channel: ['#team-hufflepuff'],
    ui: '', // empty string on purpose
  },
  SLYTHERIN: {
    display: 'Slytherin',
    channel: ['#team-slytherin'],
    ui: 'snake',
  },
}
```

Now, I'm trying to return an `array` of `objects` like so:

```
[
  { value: 'lion' },
  { value: '' },
  { value: 'snake' },
]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
const teamsUI = [Object.keys(teams).reduce((carry, item) => {
  return {...carry, ...{ ['value']: teams[item].ui  }}
}, {})];;
```

However, I get this:

```
console.log(teamsUI); // returns [ { value: 'snake' }]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[...Object.values(<obj>)].map(v => ({value: v.ui}))` or alike should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```js
const teams = {
  GRYFFINDOR: {
    display: 'Gryffindor',
    channel: ['#team-gryffindor'],
    ui: 'lion',
  },
  HUFFLEPLUFF: {
    display: 'Hufflepuff',
    channel: ['#team-hufflepuff'],
    ui: '', // empty string on purpose
  },
  SLYTHERIN: {
    display: 'Slytherin',
    channel: ['#team-slytherin'],
    ui: 'snake',
  },
}

const result = Object.values(teams).map(({ ui }) => ({ value: ui }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside nested result structure, you could take the values and destructure the wanted property formapping.

```js
const
    teams = { GRYFFINDOR: { display: 'Gryffindor', channel: ['#team-gryffindor'], ui: 'lion' }, HUFFLEPLUFF: { display: 'Hufflepuff', channel: ['#team-hufflepuff'], ui: '' }, SLYTHERIN: { display: 'Slytherin', channel: ['#team-slytherin'], ui: 'snake' } },
    result = Object.values(teams).map(({ ui: value }) => ({ value }));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the shortest way to achieve what you want

```
Object.keys(teams).map(t=>({value: teams[t].ui}))
```

Now what are you doing wrong?

Take a look at this part

```
Object.keys(teams).reduce((carry, item) => {
  return {...carry, ...{ ['value']: teams[item].ui  }}
}, {});
```

You're reducing your object to a single value with the same key called `value`. This means that the value of `teams[item].ui` of the current object in the reduce function will override the previous and hence you'll end up with the last object of that reduce function. You're finally wrapping this last object in an array which gives you what you have.

A better way to achieve that will be to do something like this

```
Object.keys(teams).reduce((carry, item, index)=>{
  carry[index] = { value: teams[item].ui };
  return carry;
}, []);
```